# Splitting documents with langchain when a sentence straddles the a page break

Tags: information-retrieval, representation

I've been following this guide to Langchain: https://learn.deeplearning.ai/langchain-chat-with-your-data/lesson/3/document-splitting

It seems like the Langchain document loaders treat each page of a pdf etc. as a separate object, so when a loaded document is then split with a text splitter, each page is split independently. However, it is quite common for concepts, sections and even sentences to straddle a page break. Logically these should be included in the same splits, but Langchain's built-in splitters seem unable to do this.

Consider this example from the linked lecture:
[image]

The speaker is asking about the backgrounds of his students and the end of the first page falls in the middle of a sentence (right after the 'How'). This divide is maintained in the splits generated by the CharacterTextSplitter. And furthermore, the overlap isn't applied, since each page is treated separately. Obviously, these are terrible splits; we'd at least like to have each full sentence reproduced in at least one split, and ideally the whole conversation about backgrounds should be it's own split.

My question is, is there any way to do this in Langchain? My first thought was that I could just merge all the page_content from each page into a single string, and then apply the splitter to that. That would lose the page number and reference metadata, but I could recover that by doing a search of part of the content of each split and comparing to the original pages returned by the loader. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1):

> My first thought was that I could just merge all the page_content...
> Is that the only way?

Sort of, Langchain doesn't provide this, You have to write your own loader/reader or join documents produced by standard loader.

---

Note, just consider implementation of PdfLoader, you can't configure it, it enforces split by page break:

````py
            # Iterate over every page
            docs = []
            for page in range(num_pages):
                # Extract the text from the page
                page_text = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
                page_label = pdf.page_labels[page]

                metadata = {"page_label": page_label, "file_name": file.name}
                if extra_info is not None:
                    metadata.update(extra_info)

                docs.append(Document(text=page_text, metadata=metadata))
            return docs
```
````

Answer (score 1):

try another tool for turning pdfs into python which does not extract content by page.
I had the same issue and solved it with pdfminer instead of pypdf:

```
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PDFMinerLoader

loader = PDFMinerLoader("example_data/layout-parser-paper.pdf")

data = loader.load()
```